# Can't log in using Firefox

Tags: support, login

For some reason, I can't log in using Firefox 15 under Win 8. I click the LiveId and enter my credentials. Then I get back to the same page **but** with only the other two options (sign up and recover password) visible.

When I try to log in using Google-account, I get an error page due to redirect issues. (That might have to do with the cookies settings, although I haven't changed them and had logged in before. Those are, of course, set to allow - both normal and third party's.)

Comment: As an aside: Firefox is much happier with just a single uppercase F.

Comment: @Arjan Hehe, coded to many MethodNames lately... I promise to spell it with only one capital "f" when it allows me to log onto SO!   :)

Comment: This is happening to me too. I am using Firefox 30 here. When I login using Google nothing happens. I have to use IE to post this comment.

Comment: @Rosdi Deactivate plugins. Empty cache. Use a new profile in FF. Reinstall. And for God's sake, why IE when you've got Cr?!   :)

Comment: The Firefox is a fresh install, zero plugins. I ditched Chrome because it is super slow.. keeps pausing every 10 minutes or so. IE 11 is very good, I might just stick to IE 11 since it is very fast and responsive.

Comment: Weird... FF rock otherwise. As for IE, it's got much better. Still, there are parts that are less than as great as FF's. Chrome is not my favorite neither, to be honest, but I guess the final choice should depend on how one use them, right? And on which feels the best.   :)

Comment: It finally works after I deleted all stackoverflow, stackexchange, and google cookies.

Comment: Put it as a reply, not as a comment.